# How to exclude a string in the middle of a RegEx string?

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

I have a lot of PHP class files, that contain methods like `findFoo()`. I want to find (with the RegEx search of my IDE or with grep) all these occurences, in order to replace them by `find()`. A proper RegEx for that would be `find[a-zA-Z0-9]+\(`. But there are some methods (e.g. `findBarByBuz()`) I'd like to exclude from my search. It's the with "`By`" or "`With`" in the name.

How to build a RegEx, that matches strings like `"find" + "stringWithoutByAndWithoutWith" + "("`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead:

```
/find(?!\w*(?:by|with))\w+\(/i
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tM4wH5/2)

`(?!\w*(?:by|with))` is negative lookahead to fail the match when `by` or `with` is found after 0 or more word character. `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

`/i` is for case insensitive matching.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just one note: Could you please remove the `-`, it's needless here. Cannot do this, since on SO edits need to affect at leas `6` characters.