# How to not match a substring in any location of the main string

Tags: regex

This might seem to be a repetitive question here but I have tried all other SO posts and the suggestions are not working for me. 
 Basically, I want to exclude strings that have a particular substring in them, either at the beginning, middle or at the end. 
 Here is an example, 
 *Max_Num_HR*, *HR_Max_Num*, *Max_HR_Num* 
 I want to exclude the strings that contain either `_HR` (at the end), `HR_`(at the beginning) or `_HR_` (in between) 
 What I have tried so far: 
 `r"(^((?!HR_).*))(?<!_HR)$"` 
 This will successfully exclude strings that have `HR_` (at the beginning) and `_HR` (at the end), but not `_HR_` (in between) 
 I have looked at [How to exclude a string in the middle of a RegEx string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37060937/how-to-exclude-a-string-in-the-middle-of-a-regex-string) 
 But their solution did not seem to work for me. 
 
 I understand that the first segment of my code `(^((?!HR_).*))` will exclude everything that contains `HR_` since I have a `^` at the beginning followed by a negative lookahead. The second segment `(?<!_HR)$` will begin at the end of the string and perform a negative lookbehind to see if `_HR` is not included at the end. Going with this train of thought, I tried including `(?!_HR_)` in between the two segments, but to no avail. 
 So, how do I get it to exclude all three `HR_`, `_HR_`, `_HR` considering *Max_Num_HR*, *HR_Max_Num*, *Max_HR_Num* as the test case?

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^(?!.*(?:_HR|HR_)).+` https://regex101.com/r/wOuPhE/1

Comment: This is not working for a string say 'Max_HRT_Num'.

Comment: You can also exclude all variations `^(?!HR_)(?!.*_HR$)(?!.*_HR_).+` https://regex101.com/r/oebixy/1 or like `^(?!HR_)(?!.*_HR_).+$(?<!_HR)`

Comment: Thanks @Thefourthbird. It is working.
As i see, `^(?!HR_)` is doing the negative lookahead at the beginning, `(?!.*_HR$)` is doing negative lookahead until the end of the string. 
I am unable to fathom how to include order in an expression. Can you please explain this considering each segment?

Comment: All 3 assertions are non consuming and are running from the start of the string. All 3 also have to pass for the pattern to go and match `.+` In theory the order of the assertions do not matter, but what you can do is if you can reason about the data which part that should not be there comes first, you can start with the assertion that is most likely to fail the fastest so that the other ones don't have to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern is missing the assertion for `_HR_` somewhere in the string.

You can add the negative lookbehind to assert not _HR at the end after the dollar sign like `$(?<!_HR)` to prevent some backtracking over the `.+`

Note that for a match only you don't need the capture groups.

```
^(?!HR_)(?!.*_HR_).+$(?<!_HR)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!HR_)` Assert not `HR_` at the start
- `(?!.*_HR_)` Assert not `_HR_` in the string
- `.+$` Match 1+ chars to not match an empty string, and assert end of string
- `(?<!_HR)` Assert not `_HR` to the left

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vTtTLo/1)

Comment: How curious, I had a task at work to write a reverse pattern for this, something like `\b(?!HR\b)(?:\w*_)?HR(?:_\w*)?\b` (it was supposed to work for words, not whole strings).

Answer (score 2):

One way to match strings that do *not* contain `'HR_'` at the beginning, `'_HR_'` in the middle or `'_HR'` at the end is to match a regular expression having a beginning-of-string anchor followed by a negative lookahead, followed by `.*`:

```
^(?!HR_|.+_HR_.|.+_HR$).*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y6YIsZ/1)

Note that lines containing `'_HR_'` at the beginning or end are matched, as per the specification.

The negative lookahead reads, "do not match 'HR_' at the beginning of the string or '_HR_' when preceded by at least one character and followed by one character (possibly more than one) or '_HR' at the end of the string.

The entire string is matched if and only if the negative lookahead succeeds.

The negative lookahead could of course be replaced by three negative lookaheads:

```
^(?!HR_)(?!.+_HR_.)(?!.+_HR$).*
```

---

Alternatively, one could determine if the string should be excluded, rather than included. A string should be excluded if and only if it matches the regular expression:

```
^(?:.+\_)?HR(?:\_.+)?$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PN6M8d/1)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
^      # match the beginning of the string
(?:    # begin a non-capture group
  .+_  # match one or more characters followed by '_'
)?     # end the non-capture group and make it optional
HR     # match 'HR'
(?:    # begin a non-capture group
  _.+
)?     # end the non-capture group and make it optional 
$      # match the end of the string
```

This second approach has an advantage over the first one in that it can be used with regex engines that do not support negative lookarounds.

Comment: Thank you @CarySwoveland.
As a follow-up on the approach, can you please tell what difference does including `$` make if it is included within the parenthesis and outside it?
How is `(?!.+_HR$)` different to `(?!.+_HR)$` ?

Comment: `(?!.+_HR$)` asserts that from the current string position there must not be one or more characters other than string terminators that are followed by `"_HR"` at the end of the string. `(?!.+_HR)$` asserts that from the current string position there must not be one or more characters (other than string terminators) that are followed by `"_HR"`, and if that assertion is satisfied, the regex engine then attempts to match `$`, requiring the current string location must be at the end of the string . That's because lookarounds do not move the regex engine's string pointer...

Comment: ...Clearly, if the current string location is at the end of the string, `(?!.+_HR)` will be satisfied, so `(?!.+_HR)$` is the same as `$`,  which obviously is  different than `(?!.+_HR$)`. Note that I've edited my answer by adding a second approach.